# CSS: How to make two divs within parent div decrease in width with parent

Tags: html, css

```
.parent {
    max-width: 750px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.block1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
}
.block2 {
    width: 650px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
}

<div class="parent">
    <div class="block1"></div><div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

I would like `.block2` get smaller as `.parent` gets smaller. `max-width: 650px;` does not work for some reason. When the browser gets to small `.block2` goes onto another line and rather then that I would like it to simply remain the maximum size.

Answer (score 1):

`flex` those muscles like so:

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
}
.flex-block {
    flex: 1 1;
}
```

See the code snippet below:

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
}
.flex-block {
    flex: 1 1;
}
br {
    clear: both;
}
.parent {
    max-width: 750px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.block1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
}
.block2 {
    width: 650px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="block1"></div><div class="block2"></div>
</div>
<br>
<strong>with flex...</strong>
<div class="parent flex">
    <div class="block1 flex-block"></div><div class="block2 flex-block"></div>
</div>
```

**Cross browser support for `flex`:**

- https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/
- http://caniuse.com/#search=flex
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have a fixed width in your second block and as soon as both blocks stop fitting in a single row they break.

If you want to use floats you could use the `calc()` css function to calculate `100%` width of the parent minus the `100px` from your first block. Leaving you with the following property in your second block:

```
width: calc(100% - 100px);
```

---

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/3hx1qLnf/)**

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
.parent {
  //max-width: 750px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.block1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: purple;
}
.block2 {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  max-width: 650px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you can get rid of floats and use `flexbox`.

---

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/ysj7u7h2/)**

---

```css
.parent {
  //max-width: 750px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}
.block1 {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}
.block2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 650px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

More info: flexbox [**here**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/flexbox/).

Answer (score 0):

1.) If you want to keep a fixed relation between the two widths, use percentage values for their `width` settings:

- 100px = 100/750*100 percent of 750px = 13.3333%
- 650px = 650/750*100
  percent of 750px = 86.6666%

2.) OR, if the 100px should remain fixed and the second div should shrink, use this setting on the second DIV:

```
width: calc(100% - 100px);
```

Comment: He is stating that only his second block should shrink according to its parent width. Your first point does not help and your second point was already included in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use 'flexbox' and neither want to use 'calc', than there is a technique using 'margins' to solve your problem. This will work if you only want block2 and the parent block to be flexible.

---

I added an example below:

```css
.parent {
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.block1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
}
.block2 {
    margin-left: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="block1"></div><div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

On block 2 I added the margin which contains the width of block 1. I also removed the 'float' part on block 2.